# Проблема при установке vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Создал пустой проект и попытался установить `vue-cli` с помощью команды `npm install -g @vue/cli`.
Далее получил следующие ошибки и замечания от интерпретатора:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated apollo-cache-control@0.14.0: The functionality provided by the `apollo-cache-control` package is built in to `apollo-server-core` starting with Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs
/apollo-server/migration/#cachecontrol for details.
npm WARN deprecated apollo-tracing@0.15.0: The `apollo-tracing` package is no longer part of Apollo Server 3. See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration/#tracing for details
npm WARN deprecated graphql-extensions@0.15.0: The `graphql-extensions` API has been removed from Apollo Server 3. Use the plugin API instead: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\yamar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\yamar\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\yamar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js' -> 'C:\Users\yamar\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\yamar\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yamar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-23T08_16_52_330Z-debug.log
```

Вопрос:
Как пофиксить эту проблему и корректно установить vue-cli?
P.S. Решения найденные в открытых источниках не помогли. 
Платформа `windows-10 pro`, `node v14.16.0`

Comment: На всякий случай, стоит добавить те способы, которые вы пробовали из других источников. Это поможет дать другим участникам сообщества дать ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Помогла команда:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli --force
```